# How to handle dodging when melee fighting?

Tags: the-last-of-us

In *The Last Of Us* it's quite common scenario to fall into a melee brawl. However if you fight with bare hands, your attack turns into long series of hits, that are often interrupted when the enemy steps back or just somehow evades a hit, that according to my experience **always** leads for Joel to get hit back. Is there any way to avoid being hit when you already missed the enemy? Step forward/backward of sideways? Any other mechanic?

Answer (score 1):

You can still counter attack with the triangle button but you must time it perfectly and it will only work if your enemy doesn't have a melee weapon (you can't counter melee weapon bare handed). Otherwise, you'll get hit.

I think your best bet would be to not get in this situation into the first place by being cautious, keep a melee weapon like a brick, a bottle or a pipe, try to do combos like throwing and dashing in, or use the environment.